# What DMA settings should I use for DCMI for STM32?

Tags: stm32, camera, dma

OV7670 is a camera with 8-bit bus communication. It's possible to connect that to a STM32 who has a DCMI communication bus.

There are two types of OV7670. One with FIFO chip behind the camera and one OV7670 that has no FIFO chip behind the camera.

When connecting a OV7670 camera to a STM32 with DCMI communication bus, there is something called DMA and it can be used to recieve the signals so the user don't need to manually read the 8-bit data bits all the time. DCMI is also a processor who recieve the 8-bit signals from OV7670 camera an DCMI can be configured to store the data into DMA.

The problem is to configure the DMA so it will work with the OV7670 camera. What DMA settings should I use for DCMI for STM32 if I'm using OV7670 camera without FIFO?

What options should I check? What type of memory should DMA be configured to? Half Word? Word?